# transparent window can't click through in macos sonoma

Tags: transparency, nswindow, macos-sonoma

i crate a fully transparent NSWindow like this:

```
NSWindowStyleMask styleMask = NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask; 
 
NSWinod *window = [[BrowserNSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,500,600) 
                                                    styleMask:styleMask 
                                                      backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                                                        defer:NO]; 
 
 
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]]; 
[window setOpaque:NO]; 
[window setHasShadow:NO]; 
 
NSCustomView *view = [[NSCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,500,600)]; 
[view setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)]; 
[view setAutoresizesSubviews: true]; 
[window.contentView addSubview:view];
```

and override the NSView drawRect function:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect 
{ 
    [[NSColor clearColor] set]; 
    NSRectFill(rect); 
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, NSCompositingOperationSourceOver); 
}
```

i call setNeedDisplay:YES to redraw the view. in macos sonoma, i found that when after multiple calls setNeedDisplay:YES, the transparent window can't click through. This feature run correctly in previous versions, like macos 13

Comment: We are having the exact same problem, the invisible was pass through the click just fine in older MacOS, but stopped working now.

Comment: Okay after line by line inspection, I found out the issue was caused by `CGContextClearRect()`, for some reason this cause the window no longer clickable.

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with the fact that the `clipsToBounds` property of NSViews are no longer set to true by default in Sonoma, so the `rect` passed to the `drawRect:` method might extend outside the view bounds.

Try either explicitly setting

```
[view setClipsToBounds: true];
```

or clipping the rect to the view bounds in `drawRect:`

```
rect = NSIntersectionRect(rect, self.bounds);
```